# Dynamically create formbean using JavaScript in Struts 1

Tags: javascript, struts1

I am trying to create a form on the fly and then submit it using JavaScript like this:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
form.setAttribute('action', '/RequestPackage.do');
```

The problem is that the action expects a form bean (i.e. PackageBeanForm.java). Is there a way for me to create such a form bean, set some field values and pass it over to the action when I submit the form using JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe I can simply create a couple of fields using JavaScript and then append these fields to the form before submitting it.

Comment: And it worked. I guess I wasn't thinking....

Comment: You have created not a formbean but a form element. The formbean is created by struts using actionconfig.

Comment: It is still picked up on the server side nevertheless.

Comment: If it picked up on the server why do you need to create a form bean? You can instantiate a bean anywhere in the code but you didn't post it and a question is off-topic because it's unclear what are you asking.

Comment: @RomanC I know I did not provide any context in my question. But in this case, I was just trying to be able to pass a different parameter from a different jsp page so that on the server side I can take different actions based on where the request is coming from.

Comment: A parameter from the JSP page is processed after the form bean is created. It's not related but different actions configured in struts-config.xml